# Changing Highcharts font size

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I'm looking at using HighCharts for a webpage, specifically:

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic/dark-green

However, the font sizes are too small. I've tried adding:

```
legend: {
        itemStyle: {
            color: '#000000',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            fontSize: '15px'
        }
```

to my js file that the site provided but this doesn't result in a font size change. Additionally I would also like to increase the size of the key (where it states Tokyo, New York, London, Berlin). This is my first time using Highcharts and I've been doing research for a couple hours now and I can't seem to find the answer. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

For legend font size, your code is working perfect. Here is [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pVua7/).

and for X-axis and Y-axis,put the font size in (x-Axis/y-Axis)->labels->style object: Here is the sample :

```
 xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
            labels: {
                style: {
                    color: 'red',
                    fontSize:'15px'
                }
            }
        },
```

Demo :http://jsfiddle.net/4VznG/

Comment: That's strange, it wasn't working in my code. I'll go back and try it again, thank you for the help!

Comment: @Nishu Tayal, In your demo font weight is not working

Answer (score 1):

I was having an issue setting fontSize of my x-Axis labels. Setting it using font in the labels worked for me:

```
xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        labels: {
            style: {
                color: 'red',
                font: '13px Arial, sans-serif'
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
xAxis: {
        categories: ['Climate Change', 'Marketing', 'Development', 'Customer Support',
                'Information Technology', 'Administration'],
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
        lineWidth: 0,
        labels: {

            style: {
                fontSize: '14px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',

            }}
    },
```