# Change Node Label Font Size on Highchart Sunburst Plot

Tags: r, highcharts, sunburst-diagram

I am using the R package, [highcharter](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/highcharter/index.html), to produce Sunburst plots. The code I'm using is functionally equivalent to the [example code provided here.](https://rpubs.com/techanswers88/sunburstchart). I want to change the font size of the labels marking each slice or section of a slice in the plot ([in this example, these labels identify specific countries, sub-continents, etc](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/sunburst)). Searching the documentation and [related StackOverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17707104/changing-highcharts-font-size), I've found plenty of information about how to modify the font in a charts title or axis labels but I haven't been able to find any information about modifying the font on sub-sections of a Sunburst plot.
I worry it might not actually be possible to do this without modifying the package because there seems to be some built-in function for hiding labels of very small sub-sections. I would appreciate any suggestions about how to modify these font sizes whether they involve modifying the package or not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with `highcharter` but most of the wrappers allow you to put in code directly in case you want to utilize the full functionality of `highcharts`.

In your case, you want to adjust the label size. That is totally do-able, I'm going to direct you to their documentation as well of how I found what you are looking for so in case you do not receive feedback that you need on SO, you can find it yourself next time.

[Direct link to documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.label)

For your question, and using the example that you cited above, you would need to adjust the by adding a `style` in `dataLabels` that are under `levels`.

In this case:

```
levels: [{
      level: 1,
      levelIsConstant: false,
      dataLabels: {
        filter: {
          property: 'outerArcLength',
          operator: '>',
          value: 64
        },
        style: {
          fontSize: '22px'
        }
      }
    }
```

This will allow you to have custom sizes for every layer in the sunburst that you would need.